# wicked wizard force to render concrete step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-gem

In rails app I use wicked gem to create wizard(https://github.com/schneems/wicked/)

I want protect my wizard and render only concrete step after check.

In fact render_wizard method can accept only instance:

```
render_wizard @product
```

Is it possible somehow render only allowed step in show action?
I need something like:

```
if params[:id] == @my_request_model.current_state
  render_wizard
else
  render_wizard @my_request_model.current_state
```

Redirecting here is not a good idea because update action already make redirect

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, are you trying to add validations to your form for each wizard step? If so, you can do the following:

In your model

```
validate :foo if step_1
validate :bar if step_2

def step_1
  form_progress == 1
end

def step_2
  form_progress == 2
end
```

Add a migration to add `form_progress` column to your model.

On each step form add a `hidden_field` for `form_progress` and set the value to the number of that step.

```
f.hidden_field :form_progress, value: 1
```

So this way, the user can only advance to the next step if they pass the validations.